# Oracle Apex - How to create a pop-up User Profile GUI as similar as the administrator one

Tags: oracle, user-interface, oracle-apex, user-profile

Good morning everyone,

This is my first post on StackOverflow. I'm actually doing a project on Oracle Apex (v.21.1.0) and my question is how to create a pop-up user profile GUI as similar as the one on the administrator page, here's what i'm talking about :

[User Profile POPUP with Light/Dark Theme Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adkYn.png)

I'm mostly interested about the light/dark theme feature. The current user profile menu for my application is looking like this :

[user profile menu of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iCv1.png)

What i want is add the same light / dark theme switch feature on the one of my application. The user profile is located on the Desktop Navigation Bar, I want the users to be able to change the theme without leaving their current page.

I hope you will be able to help me, do not hesitate to ask me questions about my request as this is my first post.

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stack overflow. APEX offers what you are describing almost out of the box. It might not be *exactly* what you are looking for, but... if it saves you a week of coding then it could be the way to go. For my example I'm going to create an application from scratch - you can add the same functionality to an existing app too if needed.

**Step 1**
Create an application. Under "Features", check "Theme Style Selection". This will allow you to configure the ability for users to choose their preferred style. Click "Create Application".

**Step 2**
Define your custom style(s). Run the application as developer and open the "theme roller". This is the link on the far right in the developer toolbar. This UI allows your to customise the color scheme for your UI. Click "Save As" and give it an alternative name. Repeat for all UI's you want.

**Step 3**
Configure the app so users can customize the theme style. Run the application, navigate to "Administration" > "Set Theme style selection". Select a style and check "Allow End Users to choose Theme Style".

**Step 4**
Delete the styles you don't want in "Shared Components" > "Themes" > Select the theme > "Styles". You can also toggle "Public" off to hide them if you don't want to delete them.

That's it. When you run the application, there is a link at the bottom for the users that shows "Customize". This allows the user to personalize the appearance of the application.

Comment: Hello Koen, thank you for answering to my post and for your solution. I came across a tutorial : https://www.sotful.com/sandroferreira-blog/dark-mode-on-your-apex-application

I really like this one and I tried it on my application but it didn't work as expected, here's what I got, i'll post it on the answer of my question so you can see the picture